# How do I relocate this tag with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm wondering if I can get your help with Jquery. Note, I cannot modify any of the html in this code because it is dynamically generated with separate widgets in wordpress.

I have a tag in a tag cloud like this with a class name "tag-link-169"

```
<a style="font-size: 1.3em; color: rgb(30, 37, 130);" title="1 topic" class="tag-link-169" href="http://blahblahblah.com/tag/poll-2/">poll</a>
```

It's parent class is `<div class="tagcloud">`

I want to take that particular tag "tag-link-169" and remove it from the tag cloud and put it before the search box, which has a class "search_form", and also be able to add an html text in front of the tag, "click this tag to see Polls"

```
<form action="http://blahblah.com/" class="search_form" method="get">
    <p>
        <input type="text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'To search, type and hit enter';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'To search, type and hit enter') {this.value = '';}" id="s" name="s" value="To search, type and hit enter" class="text_input">
        <input type="hidden" value="Search" id="searchsubmit">
    </p>
</form>
```

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need to select the element, then use [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) to put it in the right place. You could then use [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before) to insert the text:

```
$('a.tag-link-169').insertBefore('form.search_form').before('click this tag to see Polls');
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but it doesn't look great,  would it be hard to put styles on the text?

Comment: I put a class around it inside the before parentheses <div class="barf">text</div> and then styles .custom .barf {font-size: 15px;} but the font size didn't change...Is it possible that the jquery applies after the CSS so the CSS never gets a chance to work?

Comment: @Michael That should work fine. Are you sure the element is within `.custom`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('a.tag-link-169').insertBefore('.search_form').before('click this tag to see Polls');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use .find( classname ) select DOM particular tag having classname.
<div class="parenttoform"
<form action="http://blahblah.com/" class="search_form" method="get">
<p>
<input type="text" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'To search, type and hit enter';}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'To search, type and hit enter') {this.value = '';}" id="s" name="s" value="To search, type and hit enter" class="text_input">
    <input type="hidden" value="Search" id="searchsubmit">
</p>
</form>
</div>
// jquery
$('.parenttoform') .append('');
// here what to append, need html right?
//either you can create new html or give parrent div to link like below
<div class="tag-link-169"><a style="font-size: 1.3em; color: rgb(30, 37, 130);" title="1 topic"  href="http://blahblahblah.com/tag/poll-2/">poll</a></div>
now on tag click,
add first and then remove
//jquery

 $('.parenttoform') .append($('.tag-link-169').html());
 $('.tag-link-169').html('');
```